# How to compile ACM template on terminal? 2022

Tags: acm, acmart

I downloaded and extracted the [ACM Latex Template](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template) on my machine. I am trying to compile it locally to reproduce just the `sample-manuscript.pdf` file. I tried this command

`pdflatex sample-manuscript.tex`

but it loses the in-text reference numbers and also shows a bunch of warnings.

I then created a new Overleaf project based on the `samples` folder, and when I select the `sample-manuscript.pdf` file and hit the "Recompile" button, it compiles successfully. Not only does it compile successfully, it actually is also converted into double-column format for some reason (the original downloaded pdf file is single column).

What is Overleaf running to compile the code and how can I replicate it on my local terminal?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to compile the code to generate the `samples/sample-manuscript.pdf` (provided as part of the ACM LaTeX template) on my machine. Is that clear/should I phrase the question this way?

Comment: By "in-text reference", do you mean citations to references (indicating you also need to compile the bibliography before running pdflatex a few more times), or that references to section or equation numbers show up as "(??)" (indicating you need to run pdflatex another time or two)?  Overleaf takes care of those details behind the scenes.  You can also try `latexmk -pdf sample-manuscript`.  I'm not sure about single column v two column.

Comment: Almost sure that you have to  run `bibtex sample-manuscript.aux` and compile again.

Comment: Running `bibtex sample-manuscript.aux` and then `pdflatex sample-manuscript.tex` 2 times did resolve the undefined reference issue. But the generated pdf file did have a different sha256sum, so I'm not sure if it reproduced it perfectly.
Still not sure about how Overleaf compiled it into two columns instead of one.

Comment: `latexmk -pdf sample-manuscript` also worked. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`latexmk -pdf sample-manuscript` worked.

As for how Overleaf was able to compile it automatically into double-column format, I don't know.